# Insert Consecutive Id's between other Id's

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table :

```
id  x  y  z  
1   z 
3       
6      x 
7      zy
....
10000
```

I need to add id's in between the other id's that are already without deleting the data inside. Can't seem to find any solution, tryed all sorts of things but ended up making blank rows.
Kinda new to sql all together.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Just wondering...

Comment: Got a backup that i need to import to current db which is made with update only querys and need to create the rows first so that I can import them.

Answer (score 0):

Using the information you provided in the comment...

> Got a backup that i need to import to current db which is made with update only querys and need to create the rows first so that I can import them.

... and the fact that you are using MySQL, I think there is a simple solution for your problem.

Create a copy of your backup file (to have the original in case it doesn't work as expected), open it in a text editor and replace `UPDATE <table_name>` with `INSERT INTO <table_name>` (put the actual name of your table instead of `<table_name>`).

If some of the rows you want to import already exists in the table you have the following options to solve the conflicts:

1. use [`INSERT IGNORE INTO <table_name>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) as the replacement string to ignore the rows from the backup (the rows already existing in the table remain unmodified); technically, `IGNORE` doesn't ignore the rows you want to insert; it attempts to insert them and fails because they already exists but treats the failures as warnings (they are normally errors);
2. use [`REPLACE INTO <table_name>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) as the replacement string to replace the existing rows with the data from the backup; technically, `REPLACE` does `DELETE` followed by `INSERT`; it is not the best solution if the rows you want to insert are not complete.

Comment: The problem with this is the file is kinda large to resolve the comflicts manualy, if I do insert into the rows missing will be skipped and if i do replace only rows will get empty

Comment: The thing is if I manage to get the id's sorted , I can import them all and then delete every row which is empty , currently stuck on the first part.

Comment: I don't get you. The two strategies in the answer explain how to keep either the existing data or the imported data for the rows that are present in both places. You don't have to resolve anything manually. Just open the backup file in an editor, search&replace with the appropriate string, save and then import the updated file into the database.